# How do I prevent skipped tests from being checked into source control

Tags: javascript, typescript, continuous-integration, jestjs

Using jest to test our javascript / typescript code it's fairly common to wrap a test in either `describe.only` or `it.only` While writing and debugging.

This will make jest skip all other tests in the file or block, but it's an easy change to check into source control. I've done it a number of times.

What is the best way to cause tests on CI to fail if any test is skipped? Is there a linter or jest option? I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some research since asking the question and I was able to find lint rules to handle this.

For Javascript there's an eslint plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-only-tests

For Typescript there a tslint plugin in the tslint-microsoft-contrib repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib called `mocha-avoid-only`

I've tested the typescript rule and it works with jest tests. To set it up run: `npm install --save-dev tslint-microsoft-contrib` then add the following to your tslint configuration.

```
"rules": {
    "mocha-avoid-only": true
},
"rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/tslint-microsoft-contrib"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

A [linter](https://eslint.org) will do the job.

Add that to your CI job so the tests fail on GitHub etc if the bad code was committed.

You can create a [custom rule](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules) that rejects presence of `jest.it`